# How can we handle truncated label or text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

In order to test few features of the application I need to validate long alphanumeric string. And this string/label/text (whatever you can call here) supposed to truncate once given by user.

I googled and tried to find - 'how to validate truncated string ' and did not find useful info so thought question should be here.

Challenge -  I can write up a xpath for long string to validate the tag/label/text/string itself but complex part is string shows few dotes (ex thisIsLongStrin.....) at the end when got truncated.

**I would like to make sure that these 'dotes' are displaying when long string is given by user.**

Remember I can not see these 'dotes' in page source.

any thoughts or suggestions on this ?

Thanks guys in Advance.........!!!!!

suppose string is : `"thisIsLongString"`

on page it shows after truncating : `"thisIsLongStri..."`

this is what working:

```
//*[@class='abc']//*[contains(text(),'thisIsLongString')]
```

this is what working:

```
//*[@class='abc']//*[contains(text(),'thisIsLongStri')]
```

this is Not working :

```
//*[@class='abc']//*[contains(text(),'thisIsLongStrin...')]
```

(since dotes are not part of page)

**I am not sure what should be the approach to make sure that these dotes are there.**

Comment: Share source sample, desired output and your current code attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncated text is the result of applying CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis`. To check whether text truncated or not, you can use Selenium built-in method:

**Python example**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='abc']//[text()='thisIsLongString']")
assert element.value_of_css_property("text-overflow") == "ellipsis"
```

P.S. Of course you should also check (if you don't know for sure) whether string is long enough to be truncated as even if `text-overflow: ellipsis` property is applied, short string will NOT be truncated, so it might looks like

```
assert element.value_of_css_property("text-overflow") == "ellipsis" and len(element.text) > 20
```

This should check whether property applied and length of string is greater than 20 characters...

Comment: In my case, I am resizing the window to verify whether the text is getting truncated or not. Challenge is, after resize, `element.text` giving full text instead of truncated text including `...` I want to grab the truncated text which is getting displayed on the webpage. Any suggestions?